# Error in CallKit CallDirectory Extension

Tags: swift, callkit

im implementing callKit in my iOS project, im using the callDirectory extension to block and identify Numbers, the block part works perfectly , the only problem is when i try to add numbers to be identified:

```
private func retrievePhoneNumbersToIdentifyAndLabels() -> (phoneNumbers: [String], labels: [String])? {
    // retrieve list of phone numbers to identify, and their labels
    interDefaults?.synchronize()
    if let numbers = interDefaults!.string(forKey: "ident-numbers"){
        if let identities = interDefaults!.string(forKey: "ident-identities"){
            let formattedNumbers = numbers.characters.split{$0 == "*"}.map(String.init)
            let formattedIdent = identities.characters.split{$0 == "*"}.map(String.init)
            return (formattedNumbers, formattedIdent)
        }
    }
    return ([""], [""])

}
```

When i try to relaod the extension it fails with error : `Error Domain=com.apple.CallKit.error.calldirectorymanager Code=3 "(null)"`

with some testing i figured out that by replacing the `formattedIdent`  with an array of 1 element EXP: `["Spamm Caller"]` the extension works perfectly and shows no error but when i use an array with more than one element the same error shows up.
im i doing something wrong ?? thanks in advance

Comment: I was getting this error when I was developing an app while Do Not Disturb was active on my iOS.

Comment: @matusalem how i can activate Do Not Disturb in an iOS app using Callkit....?

Comment: @pramod I think it's not included in Callkit SDK

Comment: @pramod I think it's not included in Callkit SDK

Answer (score 7):

I had similar issue but the mistake I did was with error code 4. So I digged in the CXErrors and found this enum.

```
public enum Code : Int {


        public typealias _ErrorType = CXErrorCodeCallDirectoryManagerError

        case unknown

        case noExtensionFound

        case loadingInterrupted

        case entriesOutOfOrder

        case duplicateEntries

        case maximumEntriesExceeded

        case extensionDisabled

        @available(iOS 10.3, *)
        case currentlyLoading

        @available(iOS 11.0, *)
        case unexpectedIncrementalRemoval
    }
```

So basically `unknown == Code 0` and the other options increment with one. This is the full list of errors you can receive while your extension tries to handle new data up to this date.

Answer (score 2):

The error codes from CallDirectory are defined in the header `<CallKit/CXError.h>`, which includes:

```
    CXErrorCodeCallDirectoryManagerErrorEntriesOutOfOrder = 3,
```

This particular error is returned when the phone number(s) provided are out of order. Numbers must be provided in numerically ascending order.

Comment: thanks, im pretty sure that the numbers that i provided are in order !

Comment: Please check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40837561/how-to-use-call-directory-extension-to-identify-a-incoming-call/40838374#40838374

Comment: At one point, I was working with the numbers as strings and sorting the strings. However, that didn't work because the numbers could be different lengths. Once I started working with them as NSNumbers (for sorting) everything was fine. Also be sure to remove duplicate numbers.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting error 3 even though I know that my numbers are ordered correctly. What fixed it for me was commenting out the example code in the private function that is in CallDirectoryHandler file.

I'm only using caller id at this time, but if I were using blocking also, well, I'd get rid of that sample code as well.

[image: screen grab - commented out code in red]